# Entity code first issue where a field is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

To demonstrate the issue I have the following code first db context. Don't worry about the model, it doesn't make sense conceptually as it is just to demonstrate the issue.

```
public class SubjectsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    public SubjectsDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public SubjectsDbContext()
    {

    }
}

public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Course EnrolledCourse {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

[Table("Courses")]
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

}

I can create new entries ok and the data goes into the db correctly as expected.

However if I try to retrieve the Subjects by

```
dbContext.Subjects
```

I get a list correctly, but when I access the Subject object

```
dbContext.Subjects.First()
```

the Course member field is null. What is the issue?

In the debugger I get this error

> ((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Subject_6FCD2FAC29425D72CDE4D879DA7F242F07267C22C94FFE2051F99B13F76C6637)subject).EnrolledCourse' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException

Comment: your "field" is a property, and since it's virtual it's only loaded on demand. But even if you watch in the debugger, it should be loaded, maybe you need to click on it ?
Does it load if you access `dbContext.Subjects.First().Course` in Source Code ? 
If you want to include it always you have to include it. `dbContext.Subjects.Include(x => x.Course)` or you remove the virtual.

Comment: You need to dig around a little bit more. There is a page dedicated for this exact purpose. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: OK doing dbContext.Subjects.Include("EnrolledCourse") worked. Do you always have to use the Include when that member field is marked as virtual?

Comment: OK further investigation, reverted back to not using Include. When I try to access the DbContext.Subjects.First().EnrolledCourse I get an exception "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Answer (score 0):

OK firstly I made an assumption that the member field was null, it wasn't as an exception was thrown. 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command'.

Turns out I was missing MultipleActiveResultSets=true in my sql connection string.

Answer (score 0):

This is when we are talking about Lazy loading and eager loading.

**Lazy loading.** When the entity is first read, It reads only the entity but not any related data(entity). This technically ends up multiple queries sent to the database.
Eg-

```cs
dbContext.Subjects;
```

**Eager loading.** When you read the entity, related data is also retrieved along with it. This does only a single Sql join query that retrieves all of the data that's required. You specify eager loading by using the Include method.

```cs
var subjects= context.Subjects
            .Include(s ⇒ s.Courses).ToList();
```

You need to use Eager loading so that Courses will be loaded as part of the query.

Note: Lazy loading & Eager loading are very powerful concepts in Entity framework. Need to use them appropriately to achieve good performance and efficiency.